# Só é possível enviar dados do formulario para email de servidor?

Tags: php, html

Sou iniciante em php, aprendendo em casa sozinho.

Eu estava vendo um vídeo de como **enviar dados de formulário para um e-mail**, tipo aqueles campos "fale conosco" que tem em alguns sites.

E vi que em vários videos, as pessoas enviavam estes dados para um e-mail de servidor.
É possível enviar estes dados para meu e-mail "outlook", ou "g-mail"?
E-mail's deste tipo.

Comment: Sim, o método é o mesmo visto nos vídeos que você assistiu, basta colocar um e-mail normal ao invés dos emails do servidor de hospedagem.

Comment: hmm irei tentar agora mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: Já vi casos que o servidor exige que o remetente seja um e-mail do próprio domínio.

Comment: alguns como hostgator  e kinghost vc precisa configurar o sender como sendo o email do próprio domínio, mas quem está recebendo o email pode ser o gmail, outlook, hotmail, etc... o email do terra um tempo fazia verificação de antispan bem esquisito estes nao recebiam, mas de resto pode ser configurado pela própria função mail() do php ou usando uma biblioteca como a php_mailer